# how to integrate jquery form plugin and jquery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-forms-plugin

How to integrate form plugin http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ and jquery validation plugin http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation. I have been trying to integrate both the plugin but my problem is that the form gets submitted if you click the button the first time, even if the fields are empty, so in other words some how the beforeSubmit is overlooked. Then when the button is clicked the second time the the beforeSubmit takes effect and the validation is kicked in. I cant see what I am doing wrong. Can some one point me in the right direction:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

 $("#register_student_1 button").click(function (e) {


     var options = {
         target: '#reg-output1',
         beforeSubmit: showRequest,
         success: showResponse,
         type: 'post'

     };



     $('#register_student_1').ajaxForm(options);




 }),



 function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
     console.log("showResponse test");
 }



 function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {





     $("#register_student_1").validate({
         rules: {
             first_name: "required",
             last_name: "required",
             date_of_birth: {
                 date: true,
                 required: true

             },
             address_1: "required",
             nationality: "required",
             city: "required",
             country: "required",
             email: {
                 required: true,
                 email: true
             },
             current_school_name: "required",



         },
         messages: {
             first_name: "Please enter your first name",
             last_name: "Please enter your last name",
             date_of_birth: "Please enter your date of birth",

         }

     });
   }

  });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234266/jquery-jquery-form-submit-plugin-jquery-validation-plugin?rq=1 this pointed me in the right diection.

Comment: `.validate()` is the initialization for the plugin and must be called as soon as the page is loaded.  Please post your solution below.  Thank-you.